# How do I insert an external API in an extbase plugin

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I am trying to implement an external API into an extbase plugin but every time I execute the code, it can't find the class.

The API and the plugin doesn't have the same namespace. I have added the namespace at the beginning of the file. I also tried to fiddle with the ext_autoload without much success.

Since there is a lot of file in the API, I would prefer not to have to change all the namespace in the API. It would also be a bad practice to do so but I can't find any other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. Turn out you need to put the API in the "Resources/PHP" folder. Then, you include the classes using "require_once".

I found the answer here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/a-CodingGuidelines/Index.html